# Wordpress capabilities on pending post status

Tags: posts, capabilities, post-status

I have user with contributor user role. In default if you publish article as contributor you can only view it and you can't delete or edit it. But when you submit new post for review, you can do all those things (edit, delete, preview). I want to restrict edit and delete actions for contributor, if post have "Pending Review" status. I already try many user role management plugins, but none of them have such features. So I want to know is there are any other plugin or any other way to do this.

Thanks!